# Using sapply on vector of POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct, sapply

I have what may be a very simple question.  I want to process a column of POSIXct objects from a dataframe and generate a vector of datetime strings.  I tried to use the following sapply call

```
dt <- sapply(df$datetime, function(x) format(x,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
```

but to no avail.  I keep getting the following error:

```
> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  :
invalid 'trim' argument
```

When I apply this function to a single POSIXct object from the column, I have no problem. So I'm stumped at the moment about what the problem is.  Do I need to do something special with POSIXct objects?

Comment: @Chris, made some minor edits.  Please feel free to rollback if you object to anything I've done.  Best regards.

Comment: Thanks Adam. Appreciate your clarification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`format()` will take a vector argument, so 
`format(df$datetime,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` should do what you need.

When you use sapply, your objects are coerced to numeric, and so the wrong format method is being invoked.  You could coerce them back to POSIXct by using `sapply(df$datetime, function(x) format(as.POSIXct(x, origin="1970-01-01"),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))`, but unless you have a special reason to use `apply`, just use the method above