# Apply function to each column in a data frame observing each columns existing data type

Tags: r, apply, sapply

I'm trying to get the min/max for each column in a large data frame, as part of *getting to know my data*. My first try was:

```
apply(t,2,max,na.rm=1)
```

It treats everything as a character vector, because the first few columns are character types. So max of some of the numeric columns is coming out as `"   -99.5"`.

I then tried this:

```
sapply(t,max,na.rm=1)
```

but it complains about *max not meaningful for factors*. (`lapply` is the same.) What is confusing me is that `apply` thought `max` was perfectly meaningful for factors, e.g. it returned "ZEBRA" for column 1.

BTW, I took a look at [Using sapply on vector of POSIXct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482125/r-using-sapply-on-vector-of-posixct) and one of the answers says "*When you use sapply, your objects are coerced to numeric,...*". Is this what is happening to me? If so, is there an alternative apply function that does not coerce? Surely it is a common need, as one of the key features of the data frame type is that each column can be a different type.

Comment: I would pass on only the columns that have a meaningful data-type to calculate your statistic.

Comment: @Roman Thanks, that in fact is what I did yesterday, as in this particular case I already had a list of numeric column name. But it can become time-consuming for large data frames.

Comment: You can find the columns that are numeric and automate the process.

Comment: @DarrenCook As an approach, if you read the file with stringsAsFactors = FALSE and before using `apply` if you set the columns to class that they are supposed to belong to for e.g. dates as as.POSIXct, numbers as numeric etc., is that easier than wrangling with coercion inside `sapply` ?

Comment: This is an excellent question, and there still isn't really a satisfactory method for applying functions to a data.frame with mixed types. The only solution that preserves the type of each column is to use a for loop; there is no lapply method for data.frames.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If it were an "ordered factor" things would be different. Which is not to say I like "ordered factors", I don't, only to say that some relationships are defined for 'ordered factors' that are not defined for "factors". Factors are thought of as ordinary categorical variables. You are seeing the natural sort order of factors which is alphabetical lexical order for your locale. If you want to get an automatic coercion to "numeric" for every column, ... dates and factors and all,  then try:

```
sapply(df, function(x) max(as.numeric(x)) )   # not generally a useful result
```

Or if you want to test for factors first and return as you expect then:

```
sapply( df, function(x) if("factor" %in% class(x) ) { 
            max(as.numeric(as.character(x)))
            } else { max(x) } )
```

@Darrens comment does work better:

```
 sapply(df, function(x) max(as.character(x)) )
```

`max` does succeed with character vectors.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd sapply example works and answers the question perfectly (I found it worked even better if removing the as.numeric() clause, and let max work directly on the character strings)

Comment: Yes, that would generally be more useful.

Answer (score 21):

The reason that `max` works with `apply` is that `apply` is coercing your data frame to a matrix first, and a matrix can only hold one data type. So you end up with a matrix of characters. `sapply` is just a wrapper for `lapply`, so it is not surprising that both yield the same error.

The default behavior when you create a data frame is for categorical columns to be stored as *factors*. Unless you specify that it is an *ordered* factor, operations like `max` and `min` will be undefined, since R is assuming that you've created an *unordered* factor.

You can change this behavior by specifying `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, which will change the default for the entire session, or you can pass `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()` construction call itself. Note that this just means that `min` and `max` will assume "alphabetical" ordering by default.

Or you can manually specify an ordering for each factor, although I doubt that's what you want to do.

Regardless, `sapply` will generally yield an atomic vector, which will entail converting everything to characters in many cases. One way around this is as follows:

```
#Some test data
d <- data.frame(v1 = runif(10), v2 = letters[1:10], 
                v3 = rnorm(10), v4 = LETTERS[1:10],stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

d[4,] <- NA

#Similar function to DWin's answer          
fun <- function(x){
    if(is.numeric(x)){max(x,na.rm = 1)}
    else{max(as.character(x),na.rm=1)}
}   

#Use colwise from plyr package
colwise(fun)(d)
         v1 v2       v3 v4
1 0.8478983  j 1.999435  J
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, very helpful. stringsAsFactors = FALSE does make max() work as expected (but then I realized I actually wanted those fields to be factors; so casting the factors into strings when running max() works best for me).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn your data `summary (df)` provides the min, 1st quantile, median and mean, 3rd quantile and max of numerical columns and the frequency of the top levels of the factor columns.

Comment: Yes, with hindsight, I should've just used that that :-)  It's output is a bit ugly (I wanted one field per row, with a column of minimums, a column of maximums, etc.) but I suppose I just have to track down how to reformat table objects.

Comment: Another thing I would recommend is looking at the code from `summary()`.  A lot of times I'll find a base function that does close to what I'm looking for and grab the general ideas for the code from there.

Comment: sadly, summary() is also not extensible.  there is no easy way to add a mean function to it, for example.

Answer (score 2):

building on @ltamar's answer:

Use summary and munge the output into something useful!

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summary %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  select(-Var1) %>%
  separate(data=.,col=Freq,into = c('metric','value'),sep = ':') %>%
  rename(column_name=Var2) %>%
  mutate(value=as.numeric(value),
         metric = trimws(metric,'both') 
  ) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(value)) -> metrics
```

It's not pretty and it is certainly not fast but it gets the job done!

Answer (score 2):

**The best way to do this is avoid base `*apply` functions, which coerces the entire data frame to an array, possibly losing information.**

If you wanted to apply a function `as.numeric` to every column, a simple way is using [`mutate_all` from dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html):

```
t %>% mutate_all(as.numeric)
```

Alternatively use [`colwise` from plyr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/colwise), which will "turn a function that operates on a vector into a function that operates column-wise on a data.frame."

```
t %>% (colwise(as.numeric))
```

In the special case of reading in a data table of character vectors and coercing columns into the correct data type, use `type.convert` or `type_convert` from readr.

---

Less interesting answer: we can apply on each column with a for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(t)) { t[, i] <- parse_guess(t[, i]) }
```

I don't know of a good way of [doing assignment with *apply while preserving data frame structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16276667/3163618).

Comment: just note that `colwise` does not require the object to be an array to work (anymore), it requires the base type to be `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

these days loops are just as fast so this is more than sufficient:

```
for (I in 1L:length(c(1,2,3))) {
    data.frame(c("1","2","3"),c("1","3","3"))[,I] <- 
    max(as.numeric(data.frame(c("1","2","3"),c("1","3","3"))[,I]))
}
```

Comment: Recommend formatting long code on more than one line to make it easier to read on the web.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `retype()` from hablar to coerce factors to character or numeric type depending on feasability. I'd use `dplyr` for applying max to each column.

**Code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

# Retype() simplifies each columns type, e.g. always removes factors
d <- d %>% retype()

# Check max for each column
d %>% summarise_all(max)
```

**Result**

Not the new column types.

```
     v1 v2       v3 v4   
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 0.974 j      1.09 J
```

**Data**

```
# Sample data borrowed from @joran
d <- data.frame(v1 = runif(10), v2 = letters[1:10], 
                v3 = rnorm(10), v4 = LETTERS[1:10],stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- head(mtcars)
df$string <- c("a","b", "c", "d","e", "f"); df

my.min <- unlist(lapply(df, min))
my.max <- unlist(lapply(df, max))
```