# using apply with assign in R

Tags: r, loops, apply

Consider the following example:

```
Vars <- c("car","bike","lorry")
Dat <- c(10,20,22)

for (i in 1:length(Vars)){
  assign(Vars[i],Dat[i])
}
```

Here, I would like to generate three variables in the workspace named according to the entries in `Vars` and the values in `Dat`. At the moment I am using a loop, but I have been trying to remove the loop by using apply, how would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the loop if it works for you?

Comment: This is included as part of a much larger script which is driven by a for loop, so I was trying to remove this second loop thinking it would be better programming practice.

Comment: From the answer below I see that a loop may be better in this instance, it seems more readable than using mapply, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Kate, there are often several ways to get things done with R, and each has its place at the right time.... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a great example of when to use a `for` loop instead of an `apply`.
  The best solution is to leave it as it is.

if you really want to use an `*ply` loop, use `mapply`

```
 mapply(assign, Vars, Dat, MoreArgs=list(envir=parent.frame()))
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you prefer a loop over mapply? Only for better readability?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `attach` for example:

```
attach(as.list(setNames(Dat,Vars)))
```