# How to create a function in R that operates on as many vectors as desired given a data frame as an input?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create my own function to compute Coefficient of Variation given any variable (column) within a dataframe.
So far I've got the below code

```
coeffvar <- function(variable)
  { 
  abs((SD(variable) / mean(variable))*100)
  }
```

Which works for single vectors, but when the argument is a dataframe, I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(variable) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

and all outputs are NA

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 6))`. Try calling the function with `coeffvar(df$variable)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your function in a loop that iterates over `colnames(df)` or you could try implementations similar to the ones shared here:
[Apply function to each column in a data frame observing each columns existing data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303322/apply-function-to-each-column-in-a-data-frame-observing-each-columns-existing-da)

```
coeffvar = function(variable)
  { 
  abs((sd(variable) / mean(variable))*100)
  }

coeffvarS = function(df){
  sapply(df, function(x) coeffvar(x) )
}


coeffvarS(mtcars)

#Output:
    mpg       cyl      disp        hp      drat        wt      qsec        vs 
 29.99881  28.86338  53.71779  46.74077  14.86638  30.41285  10.01159 115.20369 
       am      gear      carb 
122.82853  20.00825  57.42933
```

If you wanted one function for both vectors and data.frames you could add an if statement that checks the data type of the function input.

Comment: this is a wonderful workaround! i used your example code and that worked perfectly. i will take your suggestion on an if-statement idea to combine the two functions. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code with `map_if` working only on numeric columns

```r
coeffvar <- function(variable){
do.call(cbind, map_if(variable, is.numeric, ~ abs(sd(.x)/mean(.x))*100)) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% unnest(cols = everything())
}

coeffvar(mtcars)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 11
    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  30.0  28.9  53.7  46.7  14.9  30.4  10.0  115.  123.  20.0  57.4
```